# Unbounded Convex domain

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Take an unbounded convex domain in C^n, with n>1. Suppose that it is Kobayashi hyperbolic. Is it true that it is biholomorphic to a BOUNDED convex domain? For n=1 it is true due to the Riemann mapping theorem.